# Drag a folder to dock icon in non-document-based app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have tried about every document type and delegate method by now, and my non-document-based app just doesn't accept any dropped file/folder on the dock icon.

This is the document type I copied from Apples Notes app which supports dropping folders on its icon:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>General files and folders</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.folder</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

The delegate is set correctly, otherwise my `applicationWillFinishLaunching` would not be called at all.

I tried to implement any of

- `application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool`
- `application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles filenames: [String])`

with no success. I just cannot get the dock icon to accept a drop. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Turns out I have to drag the `Debug` build to `/Applications` in order for a drag to be accepted. This is more than cumbersome, to say the least. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems very strange, but here is what I did to get it working:

- Drag the `Debug` build to `/Applications`
- Launch it and drag a file to it
- Build and run the app from Xcode again. Drop is now also accepted for the Xcode build outside of `/Applications`
- You can now remove the copied version from `/Applications`, drop still works.